# Is this an invalid object diagram, and what is association inheritance?

Tags: uml

I have one class diagram and one object diagram. Is the object diagram valid according to the given class diagram? 
Can I say it is invalid because `:C` has no `alpha` link with any `S` type object? 
Or it is valid because `:C` and `:T` have already an `alpha` link if they have a `beta` link because `C` and `T` are subclasses of the `A` and `S` classes respectively?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance specifications are invalid (or at least incomplete) because the instance of `C` has no `alpha` link to the instance of `T`.

However, if you were to draw a generalization relationship between the `beta` and `alpha` associations, that would make the instance specifications valid as they stand. A generalization between the associations would imply the unnamed end of type `T` is a subset of values for the unnamed end of type `S`. §11.5.3.1 (Associations) in the UML 2.5 spec says, "specialization means that a link classified by the specializing Association is also classified by the specialized Association."

BTW, please always name the ends of your associations. This answer would have been easier to express if I could have mentioned the association ends by name. Having names for these also reduces confusion when communicating with other people on a team.

Comment: You say "draw a generalization relationship between the beta and alpha". How would that look like?

Comment: I want to know that too.

Comment: It is a generalization arrow from the middle of the `beta` association line to the middle of the `alpha` association line, pointing upwards. The generalization arrow is identical to the generalizations that are already on the diagram.